# run multiple spiders at once and save the scraped data in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler

Hello i'm trying to run multiple spiders at once and save the scraped data in mongodb but getting error

```
my code(whole.py): https://pastebin.com/Aaq1cXMs

items.py: https://pastebin.com/KxnTqjH1

settings.py : https://pastebin.com/2v78xBV8

pipelines.py : https://pastebin.com/TREJMmap
```

whenever i do: python whole.py, i'm getting this error:

```
  C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot\spiders>python whole.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whole.py", line 2, in <module>
  from uomscrapbot.items import UomscrapbotItem
  ImportError: No module named uomscrapbot.items
```

where did i go wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the entire module structure from uomscrapbot?

Comment: Here it is: https://pasteboard.co/H9jwl8g.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the script from uomscrapbot directory. Like this

C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\**uomscrapbot**> python spiders/whole.py

**Edit**

Check your system path of python

```
import sys

print sys.path
```

You may find **C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot\spiders** in the sys path list. It means you need to add **C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot** to system path and then you can access like `import uomscrapbot`.

Edit your **whole.py** adn add this above import uomscrapbot

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot')
import uomscrapbot
```

Or you can use relative import i.e: `from .. import uomscrapbot`
Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) link for module and relative import.

Comment: i tried it but getting error: C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot\spiders>python spiders/whole.py
python: can't open file 'spiders/whole.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Don't go inside the spiders folder. Just cd into C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot\ and run python spiders/whole.py

Comment: I finally solved it. i deleted the folder 'virtual' and created a new 'uomvirtualenv' folder.because 
   when i did "sys.path.append('C:\Python27\virtual\uomscrapbot\uomscrapbot')" and print sys.path
   was getting it as 'C:\Python27\xodirtual\uomscrapbot'.
  
   Hence i changed it to "sys.path.append('C:\Python27\uomvirtualenv\uomscrapbot')", it worked perfectly

Thank you soo much, without your help, i wouldnt have been able to solve it, you are a genius sir :)

Comment: I wanted to know as well how to avoid inserting duplicate in the database, what can i change in the pipelines.py ?

Comment: use upsert and update to avoid duplicate data. Chekout this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update. You can find the same behaviour in any python mongodb package.